# Powershell Script to send email after validation

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that logs the result to a text file (this is working fine), now I need to update it to send email instead of a Log file (see actual script below). I'm kind of a new to powershell, hopefully you can help me out.

```
# details of the script
# if a file "FILE.400" is found and check the modified date, it will send a log file (txt file)
# need to update the script, to send email instead of a log file

$svr=$env:ComputerName
$date=[datetime]::Today.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
$filename = "FILE.400"
$DestLogs1 = "E:\sample\pfupdatedfin-$date.txt"
$DestLogs2 = "E:\sample\pfoutdatedfin-$date.txt"
$SrcPath = "E:\sample\$filename"

If ((Get-ChildItem $SrcPath).LastWriteTime -gt $date)
{
$date | Out-File $DestLogs1
Write-Output "Found latest FILE.400 file" | Out-File $DestLogs1 -Append
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $SrcPath).LastWriteTime | Out-File $DestLogs1 -Append
}
Else 
{
Write-Output "FILE.400 - is not updated, please verify " | Out-File $DestLogs2
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $SrcPath).LastWriteTime | Out-File $DestLogs2 -Append
}
```

Comment: Use `Send-MailMessage` instead/in addition to of `write-host`.

Comment: @vonPryz can you show me the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## the script is working as expected, in my Home network

```
$svr=$env:ComputerName
$date=[datetime]::Today.ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')
$filename = "FILE.400"
$DestLogs1 = "E:\sample\pfupdatedfin-$date.txt"
$DestLogs2 = "E:\sample\pfoutdatedfin-$date.txt"
$SrcPath = "E:\sample\$filename"

# email settings
$MyEmail = "myemail@gmail.com"
$SMTP = "smtp.gmail.com"
$To = "samplereceiver@gmail.com"
$Subject1 = "JDA-Alert || Found FILE.400 file - Successful"
$Body1 = "JDA-Alert || Found FILE.400 file - Successful"
$Subject2 = "JDA-Alert || FILE.400 file - Outdated File"
$Body2 = "JDA-Alert || FILE.400 file - Outdated File"
$Creds = (Get-Credential -Credential "$MyEmail")

If ((Get-ChildItem $SrcPath).LastWriteTime -gt $date)
{
Start-Sleep 2
Send-MailMessage -To $To -From $MyEmail -Subject $Subject1 -Body $Body1 -SmtpServer $SMTP -Credential $Creds -UseSsl -Port 587 -DeliveryNotificationOption Never
}
Else 
{
Start-Sleep 2
Send-MailMessage -To $To -From $MyEmail -Subject $Subject2 -Body $Body2 -SmtpServer $SMTP -Credential $Creds -UseSsl -Port 587 -DeliveryNotificationOption Never
}
```

Comment: Above script is working on my home network, I'm bug out when running it in the office or server at work---I encounter this error, Send-MailMessage : Unable to connect to the remote server
At C:\Users\mis.ICT-NB-15\Desktop\JDA-EOD-Checking.ps1:25 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -To $To -From $MyEmail -Subject $Subject1 -Body $Bod ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Comment: script above is already working, the reason why it is not working --- server is using an old version of Powershell (v2)---I have updated it to version 5.1 and allow smtp port in our firewall

Answer (score 0):

`Send-MailMessageis` pretty easy to use. The [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1) for cmdlets is very easy to find. Just enter the name of the cmdlet in your favorite search engine. Or use the `Get-Help` cmdlet. Here is an example how to use it just fille the Variables reasonably :

```
Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port $SMTPPort  -Credential $Credential  # -UseSsl:$UseSsl
```

`-useSsl` is a switch so it is not necessary unless it's `$true`. If you want to provide a variable to a switch parameter, don't use a whitespace but a `:` in between.

Credentials in Powershell are stored in credential objects. You can't just use a plain text password. However don't think they are stored extremly save since the password can be easly extracted if you know how. Here is how you create the necessary credential object:

```
$SecPw =  ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName,$SecPw
```

Comment: When I execute the script I encountered this error below..Send-MailMessage:Unable to connect to the remote server
At C:\Users\mis.ICT-NB-15\Desktop\JDA-EOD-Checking.ps1:25 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -To $To -From $MyEmail -Subject $Subject1 -Body $Bod ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage..when using my own connection at home, script is working

Comment: Maybe try another port like 25 without SSL. I don't know the configuration of your Mailserver... Another source of the Error could be that the [send connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/exchange/mail-flow/connectors/send-connectors?view=exchserver-2019) of your exchange don't accept mails from that server. (If it's your working PC it should work if you are able to send mails...)

Comment: yes the same laptop I'm using from home (or at work), only the connection changes. Using the script I can receive emails (by the way I'm using smtp.gmail.com)---sender and receiver are both gmail accounts

Comment: Firewall allowed for the port?